# How to get an output of a select query using oracle sql without pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, report, spool

```
SPOOL Course_Count;
CLEAR COLUMNS;
CLEAR BREAKS;
CLEAR COMPUTES;

COLUMN proId HEADING program_Id;
COLUMN proName HEADING program_Name;
COLUMN countCourse HEADING Course_Count ;
SET PAGESIZE 21;
SET NEWPAGE 0;
SET LINESIZE 30;
 
select Term.ProgramId as ProId, Program.ProgramName as ProName, count(CourseId) as countCourse 
from Term 
left join Program 
   on term.ProgramId = Program.ProgramId
where TermDescription = '&TermDescription' 
group by Term.ProgramId, Program.ProgramName;
SPOOL OUT;
```

Hi,I am new in coding. this code is not working to spool the query result. Pl/SQL procedures, dbmsout cannot be used in this. Please help me in this

Comment: What exactly are you seeing; or not seeing that you expect to see? And how are you running this - in which tool, and with which command (e.g. SQL Developer with 'run statement' or 'run script')? Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the output file? (Or output file*s* - `spool out` will start a new file called `out.lst`; you probably meant `spool off`.)

Comment: "Not working" provides absolutely no information about the issue you have. Please, adf more details to the question